# How Are Oracles Registered and Randomness Fulfilled in Chainlink's VRFCoordinator?

Tags: chainlink

I am learning about VRF by studying Chainlink's contracts and have some questions about their security. I understand that randomness is generated by an oracle registered with the [VRFCoordinator contract](https://etherscan.io/address/0x271682DEB8C4E0901D1a1550aD2e64D568E69909). However, I noticed that there are only four registered oracles according to the `getRequestConfig` function.

My questions are:

1. Who is able to register an oracle, and is it a centralized process?
2. Which oracle is responsible for fulfilling the randomness? Is it the fastest one?
3. If someone were to register 100 oracles, how could we trust the randomness when they can select any of the 100 candidates?

Thank you in advance for your help!